# Dynamically Select Price once Product is selected in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have This in The Form

```
    <%= simpleform_for @customer_bill do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :product_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_id,Product.all,:id,:title, :prompt => "Select a Product", :style => 'width:150px;' %>

     <%= f.label :price %> 
    <%= f.text_field :price, :size=>20, :id =>"price", :class =>"price" %>
    <br/>
/*rest of code*/
```

In The Products Table I Have 'Product title' and 'price'. And i have the necessary association made between customer bill and Products model.

Once the Product is selected Price should automatically come. WHich is the best way to do it?? Ajax/ Jquery How  can i Proceed with the Problem???? Any Guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Product.all in a view ain't good design, create a helper instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data-xxx attribute of your select-tag to store prices and let javascript to handle it:

JavaScript:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#products').change(function() {
            var product_id = $(this).val()
            var price = eval($(this).data('prices'))[product_id]
            $("#price").html(price)
        })
    })
```

Template (it's Haml, but I guess you'll get the idea even if you're ERb-guy):

```
= simple_form_for ........ do |f|
    - prices = Hash[Product.all.map{|p| [p.id, p.price]}].to_json
    = f.association :product, input_html: {data:{prices: prices}, id: 'products'}
    = f.label :price, id: 'price'
```

Note the using of `f.association` instead `f.collection_select`. I think in your case it's simpler to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot jdoe. Helped alot

Comment: @bharath I couldn't withstand how highlighter treats my code :) I changed it to specify id's via hash.

Comment: Kool :) now looks better...but itseems my jquery is not working....the code above is not been rendered...!! wat may be the problem?? any problem with gem dependency???

Comment: Where/how did you put this script?

Comment: inside a separate js file and called it in the form..!!

Comment: "Called"? What do you mean? I've used unobtrusive approach: you don't have to call it explicitly. If you put it in `assets/javascripts/some_file.js` then It'll automatically 'glue' itself to your select-tag with id `products`.

Comment: yeah i had put a javascript include tag which i removed now and yet it is not working. and i have changed the $ sign to jQuery cause it was giving error in firebug console. is that casuing problem??

Comment: Just to make sure where your problem is: 1) copy my js again, make no changes; 2) just in case put in it `alert(1)` to know if your script loads; 3) check your HTML: make sure your `<select ...>` contains `id="products"` 4) take a look at your label -- it has to have id `price`.

Comment: followed all the steps...getting the following error in the firbug console **$ is not a function  

$(function() {**

Comment: Maybe you've removed jQuery library from your application's js-mainfest? Or you could change it so that jQuery is loaded after your custom scripts?

Comment: I rectified the previuos errors, Now i m getting this error **eval(jQuery(this).data("prices")) is undefined**

Comment: Show me your `<select ....>` from your HTML. Use http://pastebin.com/ if it is too long.

Comment: Your very first line contains 2 errors: id has to be: product*s* (plural). And `id="products"` has to be inside the `input_html` Hash. Why did you change my offered code? )

Comment: Sorry... i had actually changed in the js file as well...both are 'products' now :) still m getting error..! :(

Comment: It is just above the f.association..frgt to put that in code i sent
`<%- prices = Hash[Product.all.map{|p| [p.id, p.price]}].to_json %>` This is how i have put before f.association

Comment: "pastebin" me your modified js + form as they are now.

Comment: I had problems with $ sign again...so i changed the $ to jQuery..I ll Post the code now...

Comment: Comments are not the place to have a rolling debug session.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use jQuery with ajax. You have two choices to do that :

- Your ajax request return html code -> You change a block in the page
  to update it with new price
- Your ajax return json -> you use javascript functions to parse json
  and update your select.

Comment: The author populates his page with all the products, so I guess it won't hurt to put their prices there also.

Comment: So you were too opinionated when using the word "best" :-)

Comment: You are right, it seems all the products are in the page (strange idea) :) I correct my answer.

Comment: @jdoe- Hey i am not able to send chat messages here...dunno why...and hey i solved the problem. The problem was with jquery in my Windows machine...i reinstalled it and the whole code is working. THANKS ALOT for ur help. Saved me lot of time.

Comment: @Sebastien Thanks For the advice. ll help me in future. :)